Highlight the cursor of current directory in different color with respect to cursors higher and lower in the file system tree
I am using ranger for a few days now which I find a great piece of software and I was wondering if it possible to set the highlighting of the cursor to a different color for the one poiting to the current directory or file that ranger points to as it might get confusing when there are pointers in directory higher or lower in the file system tree
